# How to analyze HTML source code in textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, dom, textarea

Hi I'll explain my problem. I am creating a site where several users through a login can insert the source code of a page, in particular of a browser game (I had thought of doing this through a textarea). Next I have to analyze this source code and get some data from it by forming a table in a reserved area.

I have several questions to ask, does the source code that users paste into the textarea need to be saved in the database? I saved it like longtext but when I try to print it I don't get the actual code but a series of / n / n / n / n / n / n / n / n / n /.

How can I then analyze this code and get the data I need? Thank you very much in advance, I hope I have explained myself well.

For example this is my textarea code in caserma_admin.php:

```
  <form action = "add_caserma.php" method = "post">
  <textarea name="caserma" class="textarea" rows="30" cols="50"></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit" class="submit_textarea" name= "invia"> Invia </button>
  </form>
```

Next in add_caserma.php i insert html source code of users in the databases:

```
    $caserma = $_POST["caserma"];
    $username = $_SESSION["utente"];
    
    
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione , $username); //protezione stringhe
    $caserma = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione , $caserma); //protezione stringhe
    
    $query = "UPDATE utenti SET caserma = '$caserma' WHERE username = '$username'";

    $trova_utente = mysqli_query($connessione, $query);
  if(!$trova_utente){
    die('RICHIESTA FALLITA!' . mysqli_error($connessione));
  }else{
    $_SESSION["caserma"] = $caserma;
  }
}
```

In test.php i try to stamp it:

```
<?php include 'database.php' ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
echo $_SESSION["caserma"];
 ?>
```

When I print this source code the code itself is replaced by n / n / n / n / n /, but that's not the problem because I'm not interested in printing it was a simple curiosity. What interests me is how to get data from this source code inserted in the textarea.
In my database the source code is something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="mainLayout">
    <head>
        <title>Anglosphere x3</title>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="content-language" content="en-US" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
...
...
```

Instead when i print:

```
r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n \r\n
\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n
\r\n 
\r\n
\r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n
```

I want to clarify that I am not interested in printing the code but in taking data from the tables

Comment: I would suggest you to use some editor from a 3rd party library like the ckeditor that would handle the encoding and decoding of the text. Since the text has to be stored and processed in its original raw format, you need to check if the network sustains the data or not and yes you can store it in database using long text or blob, just define the maximum character limit at the editor also.

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: done, i have changed the description of the original question

Comment: You'll need to post the part where you output the string that's only showing the update query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simplexml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) for this.

```
$html = <<<HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="mainLayout">
    <head>
        <title>Anglosphere x3</title>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="content-language" content="en-US" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
</html>
HTML;

var_dump(simplexml_load_string($html));
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/vbJ3T).

Comment: So as I understand it SimpleXML transforms an XML document into a data structure you can iterate as a collection of arrays and objects. To do this I have to use this syntax:

    $ html = <<< HTML
    ...text...
    HTML;
    var_dump (simplexml_load_string ($ html));

Only thing, can I pass the text to be inserted through a session variable? because I have it on the database

Comment: Its just a string. The `<<<BLA` is just a notation to encapsule a string called [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) - So yes, you can put any string in there, no matter where it comes from.

Comment: ok so i can write in this way?

     $CasermaUtente = $_SESSION["caserma"];
     $html = <<<HTML
     $CasermaUtente;
     HTML;
     var_dump(simplexml_load_string($html));

Comment: Technically yes, but you can just write `var_dump(simplexml_load_string($_SESSION["caserma"]));`

Comment: it show me these 3 warnings:

**Warning:** simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\----------------------.php on line 10

**Warning:** simplexml_load_string(): \r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://ww in C:\----------------------.php on line 10

**Warning:** simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\----------------------.php on line 10
bool(false)

Comment: That means you input is no valid xml/html. Read the error and act accordingly. Thats the reason why I did provide an example.

Comment: I tried to simulate as you advised me but it says the code is too long, the source code is about 3000 lines, I couldn't post it all. Anyway thanks a lot for information, I will read up on this topic.

Comment: According to the error you posted, I dont need to see 3000 lines. It says the error is on line 1.